# How to create css shadow effect

Tags: html, css

can I create the shadow effect below the box with CSS? is this possible?[image]

Comment: Look at here to get ideas http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-drop-shadows-without-images/demo/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.box {
    width:70%;
    height:200px;
    background:#d6d6d6;
    margin:40px auto;
    position: relative;
}

.box:before, .box:after
{
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  background: #444;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 15px #444;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 15px #444;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 15px #444;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}

.box:after
{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Yp3e5/)**

Comment: Thanks, I also created a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/v5Vuh/